# Button gradient borders with transparent background

Tags: css, border, gradient, linear-gradients, border-image

Here is the result I would get:
[image: Gradient border / Gradient background on hover-over]

So the default button has gradient border with transparent background (as I want to see the parent's background through it).
When the user hover over the button I want to fill it with the same gradient has the borders.

So first I tried with border-image property and with an .svg image of my border:

```
button {
  background: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-image-source: url(assets/images/icons/border.svg);
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
  border-image-slice: 49;
  border-image-width: 100px;
  border-image-outset: 6px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

So I have more or less the result I was waiting for:
[image: Result]

Now, how to manage the hover-over animation and fill the background with no size changes !?

Maybe border-image isn't the best way to do it ?

Thanks for your help, Cheers !

Comment: can you share the SVG you have created?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can get it in here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/02be51549919378264f1789c3264d9f520180816002553/0f52af

Comment: @TemaniAfif for now I'm using an svg, but maybe we can reproduce the same effect with colors ... ? Here is my correct linear-gradient: border-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #2ae88a 0%, #08aeea 100%);

Answer (score 3):

An idea is to rely on `background-attachement:fixed` since you are using a background image and we can simulate the transparent effect BUT you will have the scrolling effect on the background:

```css
.container {
  padding:100px 0;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=1069) fixed;
}
.button {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#fff;
  margin: auto;
  border:3px solid transparent;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=1069) padding-box fixed,
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #2ae88a 0%, #08aeea 100%) border-box;
}
.button:hover {
  background:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #2ae88a 0%, #08aeea 100%) border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, it's helped me finding the proper solution, I will update my post.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

Ok finally I found a workaround to accomplish my desire, it almost all come from the SVG file. I tweak a little my SVG in order to get two different path on with the gradient stroke but not filled, and the other one gradient filled but no stroke. One over an other and the opacity is the master key :)

```
<a type="button" href="#">
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 250 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="linearGradient-1">
          <stop stop-color="#08AEEA" offset="0%"></stop>
          <stop stop-color="#2AE88A" offset="100%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="none" d='M50,95 a45,45 0 0,1 0,-90 h150 a45,45 0 1,1 0,90 h-150' />
  <path class="icon--plain" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" d='M50,95 a45,45 0 0,1 0,-90 h150 a45,45 0 1,1 0,90 h-150' />
</svg>
Invest now
```

Here comes the CSS (I am using SCSS btw):

```
a[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 1.75rem;
  z-index: 0;

  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;

    path {
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease;

      &:first-of-type {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: url(#linearGradient-1);
        stroke-width: 3;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      &.icon--plain {
        opacity: 0;
        stroke: none;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
    }    
  }

  &:hover {
    path {
      &:first-of-type {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      &.icon--plain {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably best to use a CSS-only solution, if you can. You want to avoid the extra complexity and browser-issues involved with SVG.

Comment: which browser-issues with SVG are you talking about ? Honestly there are no complexity in that solution IMO, the "hard" part is to conceive the SVG file, the rest is just easy css stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with CSS gradients. Have a look at my solution below:

```
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  color: white;
}

.box:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
}
```

Note, you will need to add your own gradient into the `.btn` class under `background-image: linear-gradient`...

Play around with my solution here:
https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/mjYNeN

Comment: this is not transparent, he's using an image as background not color

Comment: Only issue is the border-radius.